# Where, in Qemu source code, KVM_RUN (or other ioctls) are called?

Tags: c, linux, virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to understand QEMU source code. I started in the main function and learned lots of things about the Glib main loop and the events defined there. However, I couldn't find the part where it starts the CPU. So I had the idea to search for the KVM ioctl names, because QEMU must call them somewhere to start and run the virtual CPUs if the KVM option is enabled. I started with `KVM_RUN`

I've found that the `KVM_RUN` ioctl is called here

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/accel/kvm/kvm-all.c#L2346

which lives inside the function `kvm_cpu_exec` which is called here:

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/cpus.c#L1246

which lives inside the function `qemu_kvm_cpu_thread_fn` that is called/passed as a callback here

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/cpus.c#L2007

which lives inside the function `qemu_kvm_start_vcpu` that is called here

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/cpus.c#L2076

which lives inside `qemu_kvm_start_vcpu` which lives insde `x86_cpu_realizefn`, in the case of i386 architecture:

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/target/i386/cpu.c#L6472

which lives inside `x86_cpu_common_class_init` that is called here:

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/target/i386/cpu.c#L7231

which is defined as a struct member here:

https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/target/i386/cpu.c#L7300

Then I simply reached the end of the call stack. I don't know who calls this function, as it is defined as a member of a struct. I don't know the name of the object so I could search for `object->class_init(` in the code.

I tried with other ioctls but I end up into the same thing.

So, where does the CPU is started?

*ps: I used vscode + microsoft cpp intellisense to quickly find where a function is called, I just click with the rigth button on the function name and "go to definition"*

*ps2: qemu main loop begins here: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/17e1e49814096a3daaa8e5a73acd56a0f30bdc18/softmmu/main.c*

Comment: Your not looking for the definition, you need to search for references to that field in the struct/class field/member.

Comment: @jwdonahue I didn't understand. Can you explain it better?

Comment: If you want to find out how execution gets to kvm_cpu_exec(), the easy way is to compile QEMU with debug symbols enabled (configure's --enable-debug option will do that), and run it under a debugger like gdb. Set a breakpoint on kvm_cpu_exec() and then just look at the stack backtrace when you hit it.